# Registert New User to Openfire server using XMPP in iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire

I am trying to register a new user to an open fire WITHOUT using inbound registration, also some other settings are:
bool allowSelfSignedCertificates = NO; bool allowSSLHostNameMismatch = NO; bool useSSL = NO. I sow a few examples on stackoverflow but none of them was good for me or I didn't grasp the concept...

Here is my code:

-> .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "XMPP.h"
#import "XMPPRoster.h"

@interface SignUpViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate, XMPPRosterDelegate, XMPPStreamDelegate>
{
    XMPPStream *xmppStream;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) XMPPStream *xmppStream;

@end
```

-> .m file

```
- (void)signUpButtonFunction{
    NSLog(@"SignUp function");

    [[self xmppStream] setHostName:@"IP_ADDRESS"];
    [[self xmppStream] setHostPort:5222];
    XMPPJID *jid=[XMPPJID jidWithString:emailTextField.text];
    [[self xmppStream] setMyJID:jid];
    [[self xmppStream] connectWithTimeout:3.0 error:nil];

    NSMutableArray *elements = [NSMutableArray array];
    [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"username" stringValue:@"venkat"]];
    [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"password" stringValue:@"dfds"]];
    [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"name" stringValue:@"eref defg"]];
    [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"email" stringValue:@"abc@bbc.com"]];

    [ xmppStream registerWithElements:elements error:nil];

}


//server connect delegate methods are not working at least it doesn't enter in them
- (void)xmppStreamDidRegister:(XMPPStream *)sender{


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Registration" message:@"Registration Successful!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}


- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotRegister:(NSXMLElement *)error{

    DDXMLElement *errorXML = [error elementForName:@"error"];
    NSString *errorCode  = [[errorXML attributeForName:@"code"] stringValue];

    NSString *regError = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ERROR :- %@",error.description];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Registration Failed!" message:regError delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    if([errorCode isEqualToString:@"409"]){

        [alert setMessage:@"Username Already Exists!"];
    }   
    [alert show];
}
```

These is the library that I am using:
[git library](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)

and also I want to point out that my code is not entering the delegate methods

UPDATE:

- changed the signUpButtonFunction to:

  ```
  xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
  [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
  [[self xmppStream] setHostName:@"IP_ADDRESS"];
  [[self xmppStream] setHostPort:5222];
  [[self xmppStream] setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"abc@newrosoft.com"]];
  [[self xmppStream] connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:nil];

  NSMutableArray *elements = [NSMutableArray array];
  [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"username" stringValue:@"username"]];
  [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"password" stringValue:@"password"]];
  [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"name" stringValue:@"eref defg"]];
  [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"email" stringValue:@"abc@newrosoft.com"]];

  [ xmppStream registerWithElements:elements error:nil];

  NSError *error = nil;
  if (![xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
  {
      UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error connecting"
                                                      message:@"See console for error details."
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alertView show];
      NSLog(@"%@",error);
  ```
- And I get the error:

Error Domain=XMPPStreamErrorDomain Code=1 "Attempting to connect while already connected or connecting." UserInfo=0x7fdc2af1f1c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Attempting to connect while already connected or connecting.}

And if I comment the line:

```
[ xmppStream registerWithElements:elements error:nil];
```

then the error disappears, but it stills doesn't enter the delegate methods.

Comment: you are connecting twice, delete first `[[self xmppStream] connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:nil];`

Comment: Actually you need to connect stream before registering new user. Try connecting to xmppstream with new userid. From xmppStreamDidConnect delegate you will be able to know that stream got connected. Please try to initialise registration from this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after search on the matter I found out that on the openFire can be installed a plugin that allows normal registration, so I have implemented the next method for the registration:

```
NSString *urlToCall = @"http://MyIP:9090/plugins/userService/userservice?type=add&secret=BigSecretKey&username=testUser&password=testPass&name=testName&email=test@gmail.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToCall];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if ([responseString  isEqual: @"<result>ok</result>\r\n"]) {
    NSLog(@"user created");

} else {
   NSLog( @"user NOT created");
    NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Laur Stefan**

First Download New Demo From https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

Then

in - (void)goOnline Change

```
 #warning Set here Server Name...
        if([domain isEqualToString:@"rakeshs-mac-mini.local"])
        {
            NSXMLElement *priority = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"priority" stringValue:@"24"];
            [presence addChild:priority];
        }
```

Then

in - (BOOL)connect Method..

```
#warning Set Username as username@servername
    myJID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@rakeshs-Mac-mini.local",myJID];

    [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID]];
    password = myPassword;

    NSLog(@"username: %@,Password : %@",myJID,myPassword);
```

After Connection to YOur Server From OpenFire , 
You can Got Response From Below Method.

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
```

***//Try Above tested Code, if any problem tell us..***

Comment: what is this actually doing? inbound registration? vote up for support

Comment: @LaurStefan, first of all in my case, i have created few user in **Openfire** Server which is created in my PC. Then After I have login through Adium & **XMPP** Demo with this two user...

SO , it is working perfectly. i Have **tested** it.

Answer (score 0):

//this method is used at Sing UP view controller

```
-(BOOL)createNewAccountForXmppWithUserName:(NSString*)userNameJID  andPassword:(NSString*)userPassword{
    if (userNameJID == nil || userPassword == nil) {
        return NO;
    }
    NSString *domain = @"abc.com";
    self.xmppStream.hostName = domain;
    int port = 5222;
    self.xmppStream.hostPort = port;
    useSSL               = NO;
    customCertEvaluation = NO;
    NSString * userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@abc.com",userNameJID];
    XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:userName resource:nil];
    self.xmppStream.myJID = jid;
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success;
    success = [[self xmppStream] registerWithPassword:password error:&error];
    if(![[self xmppStream] isConnected])
    {
        if (useSSL)
            success = [[self xmppStream] oldSchoolSecureConnectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error];
        else
            success = [[self xmppStream] connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error];
        password = userPassword;
        success = [[self xmppStream] registerWithPassword:password error:&error];
    }
    else
    {
        password = userPassword;   
        success = [[self xmppStream] registerWithPassword:password error:&error];
    }
    if (success)
    {
        isRegistering = YES;
        NSLog(@"Successfully Register on XMPP Server");
    }    
    return YES;

}
```

To show online/offline status we have to implement "NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate"

```
@interface AKSMessageViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
{
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
}
```

And implement

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    //remove previous data or clear array

    [[self xmppUserArray] removeAllObjects];
    [[[AKSGetCareerGlobalClass SharedInstance] onlineUserArray] removeAllObjects];


    //get data from core data
    self.xmppUserArray=[[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];


    for (int i=0; i<[[self xmppUserArray] count]; i++) {

        if ([[[[self xmppUserArray] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"sectionNum"] integerValue]==0) {
            //this is user is online
            [[[AKSGetCareerGlobalClass SharedInstance] onlineUserArray] addObject:[[[self xmppUserArray] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"nickname"]];

        }
    }


    [[self msgTableView] reloadData];

}
```

//And

```
#pragma mark NSFetchedResultsController
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (fetchedResultsController == nil)
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext_roster];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:moc];

        NSSortDescriptor *sd1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sectionNum" ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor *sd2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayName" ascending:YES];

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sd1, sd2, nil];
        //NSSortDescriptor *sd2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayName" ascending:YES];

        //NSString *myJID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userJID"];
        //NSLog(@"My JID ====>%@",myJID);

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subscription=='both'"];


        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

        fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                       managedObjectContext:moc
                                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionNum"
                                                                                  cacheName:nil];
        [fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];


        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
        {
            DDLogError(@"Error performing fetch: %@", error);
        }

    }

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: I am using above code  created successfully But not showing as online and not calling didAuthenticate Method but when close my app and restart then it is showing as connected and online.where I am missing please help me

Comment: @Bittoo. see updated code. "sectionNum" == 0 mean online user. this method "controllerDidChangeContent" will call when any user goes online/ offline. you didn't need "didAuthenticate" method.

Comment: Thanks for the replay but in my scenario i need to fetch the contacts from phone it is also working fine but not showing first time when i close my app and reopen then i fetch it showing my contacts and also call the didauthenticate method. first time only getting problem please help me

Comment: and my nsfetched controll showing empty for first time if i reopen then it is working fine

Comment: send "presence"  to server as you login or launch app.

Comment: @avijith Thanks for the replay but my problem not with the online users with  signup when i am signup first time it not authenticated. but when close and reopen then it is authenticated